# Looking for Good Thin Scrollviewer style in XAML WINRT

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have implemented semantic zoom in my page, 
1) when i move screen from left to right with HAND(MY Computer is touch enabled) for reading contents off the screen,i see thin and good scrollviewer horizontally appears when i move left to right and disappears after some time, if application is kept idle. 
2)When i bring my Mouse and Hover on Semantic Zoom, I see default/ larger thicker scrollbar horizantal. But i want to have one goood looking scrollviewer which eatly looks like scrollviewer mentioned in Step1 . Let me know if there are any good looking scrollviewer which thinner

Comment: An example would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make the ScrollViewer always show the thin "panning indicators" when mousing over it instead of showing the traditional ScrollBars with draggable thumbs.  It's easy to do this and I'll show you an example, but please keep in mind you could be creating an accessibility problem.  If a user does not have a touch-enabled device, the traditional ScrollBars with draggable thumbs allow the user to scroll.  Without these, the user has to resort to keyboard or mouse wheel to scroll (assuming the user has a mouse wheel input device, or that the ScrollViewer has focusable content the user can tab into).  This creates a potential accessibility problem for non-touch users.

To make sure we're referring to the same thing:

- [traditional mouse scrollbar](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=7F261EE6022A7FFF!18518&authkey=!AHNy0Vce3EjgseA&v=3)
- [panning indicator](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=7F261EE6022A7FFF!18517&authkey=!AAxbxugiUVMIjyg&v=3)

By default, the ScrollViewer shows the panning indicator when the user performs a touch gesture on the ScrollViewer, and shows the traditional mouse scrollbar is shown when the user moves the mouse above the ScrollViewer or clicks on the ScrollBars/Thumbs.

To make the ScrollViewer show the panning indicators for mouse input, you need to perform these steps:

1. Open your project in Expression Blend.  Right-click your ScrollViewer and select "Edit Template > Edit a Copy...".
2. Dig into the ScrollViewer's template and find the vertical ScrollBar.  Right-click the ScrollBar and select "Edit Template > Edit a Copy...".
3. Open the XAML page where the new templates were created, either in Blend or in VS.  Find the ScrollBar template that you created.  Inside of it, find this line: `<VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollingIndicatorStates">`.
4. Inside the "ScrollingIndicatorStates" VisualStateGroup, copy the code inside the "TouchIndicator" VisualState:

   ```
   <Storyboard>
       <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="HorizontalPanningRoot"/>
       <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="VerticalPanningRoot"/>
       <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="HorizontalRoot"/>
       <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="VerticalRoot"/>
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalRoot">
           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
               <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                   <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
               </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
           </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
       <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalRoot">
           <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
               <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                   <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
               </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
           </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
       </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
   </Storyboard>
   ```
5. Paste this code into the body of the "MouseIndicator" visual state, overwriting what's already there.
6. Also, if you show a horizontal ScrollBar as well, make sure to update the horizontal ScrollBar in your modified ScrollViewer template to use the ScrollBar template you created.

So, overall pretty simple.  We just had to copy the animations from the "TouchIndicator" state and paste them into the "MouseIndicator" state.  Full code example is here:
https://github.com/finnigantime/Samples/tree/master/examples/Win8Xaml/ScrollViewer_PanningIndicatorsOnly